# Laravel(xampp) Got error while trying to migrate real website to virtual host : SQLSTATE[42S02]

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm new at Laravel, I got this error when I tried to migrate a real website to XAMPP sevrer

The problem occured after I executed the following commands in the command line:

```
composer install 
php artisan key:generate
php artisan migrate
```

In Connection.php line 664:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table '<mydatabase>.setting' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `setting` limit 1)

In Connection.php line 326:

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table '<mydatabase>.setting' doesn't exist

Comment: Looks like you simply forgot to create tables in the database you're using. You may export the database from live database using any of the tools available on the internet and then import it.

Create an SQL dump, then import it into your XAMPP server MySQL database. IIRC you have phpmyadmin available straight away.

Comment: @SergeyTelshevsky Thx you so much. That's what I think so but my customer, he gave me only the "public" folder(I've ask him about the live database but he didn't give it to me T^T). Moreover, he told me that his dev. team can run the website without the live database, just create the new one!. So, I got this problem lol. However, thank you so much mannn

Comment: Did you configure the database connection in .env and config/database.php?

Comment: @ManuelEduardoRomero yes,I tried. So, I don't have any clues to make it work. Thanks mannn

Comment: @WerachaiTamboon probably you may have some script in the project that creates the database on development server for you. It could be called something like migration. Considering you're using Laravel, you should check out the docs for that

Comment: @SergeyTelshevsky Now, I got the exported database from live website. Everything seems to work fine,thank you anyway mannnn

Comment: @WerachaiTamboon consider closing (removing) your question or writing an answer yourself to help others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, I got the exported database from live website. Everything seems to work fine,thank you anyway mannnn